# CORS – Cross Origin Request Blocked – The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains invalid value

Tags: javascript, cors

I am having problems with CORS, which I can't seem to resolve.

My setup:

- Router/Hotspot on network **A**
- Webserver on network **B**

What I am trying to do, is... The user inputs his email into the Hotspot entry page, and when he clicks submit, the email is sent to the webserver (currently using XAMPP), **this is where the CORS problem occures.**

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://myIpAddress:8080/DBinsert.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing.

Perviously I had `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` set and I had no CORS problems...

I have tried adding this code to the very beginning of my php, but it still doesn't work...

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://10.5.50.*');`

I have also tried

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://10.5.50.*:8080');`

and it doesn't work...

The computers IP is 10.5.50.3

Any help and explenations would be welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the exact error messages the browser is logging in the devtools console? In particular, what is the origin cited in the *from origin [origin]* part of the error message?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: HTTP status code is 200. The exact error message (I only get one) is: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myIpAddress:8080/DBinsert.php' from 'http://10.5.50.1' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains invalid value '10.5.50.*'.`

Comment: The value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header must either be the single character `*` or else an exact origin value such as `http://10.5.50.3`. Browsers do an exact match against the value, so `10.5.50.*` won’t match anything — browsers don’t interpret the asterisk in `10.5.50.*` as a wildcard. And not also that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value must include the protocol part; so `http://10.5.50.3` is a valid value for the header, but `10.5.50.3` would not be.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Though I could "tighten" the control, but I guess thats not possible. Please write an anwser so I can accept it =) Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response-header values must either be the single character `*` or else an exact origin value, such as `http://10.5.50.3`.

Unless the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value is just the character `*`, then browsers do an exact match against the literal value of the header; therefore, `10.5.50.*` (for example) won’t match anything — because browsers don’t interpret the asterisk in `10.5.50.*` as a wildcard.

Note: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` values must include the protocol part; so `http://10.5.50.3` is a valid value for the header, but `10.5.50.3` would not be.

Answer (score 1):

Use Access-Control-Allow-Origin with just the domain part eg.: https://www.yourdomain.com

NOTE: remove the last "/" char from the domain, or it will not work

This will resolve any issues with router's ip, or proxies, so just better use a domain name, also if someday you change the server (and changes the IP) then you will not need to worry about changing again all the CORS policies.

I'm on c# using

`HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.example.com")`